# See history of who all opened a particular file

Tags: linux, unix

How can I know who opened a particular file recently but might not have kept it opened at the moment?

Anyone has an idea?

Comment: There has to be a way to find who all opened a particular file in unix.. I think this is nominal to expect from such a powerful OS.

Comment: keeping track of which users opened a file is not necessarily useful for most files or workloads.  For example, many computers have only one user, so that user opens all the files and nobody else opens any. Many servers run a process that has its own user accounts (httpd, sql server, etc) and does not use the OS's users accounts; any files it opens are opened by the user account under which the service runs.  Also for many computers keeping track of this list will cause a significant impact to performance and disk usage.  Your best bet is probably, as scoopdreams suggested, to enable auditing.

Comment: You can't do this by default on Windows either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, if you mean in the past, you probably cannot, unless you have some kind of audtiting turned on.

Assuming you do not, you can look at the permissions of the file and the directories to see who has has access. You can grep everyone's .bash_history file for the file name.

And that is about it, as far as I know.  If they still have it open, you could use lsof, for instance.

Answer (score 9):

You can use [**auditd**](http://linux.die.net/man/8/auditd) package as suggested in another answer. A simple use would be:

> auditctl -w /etc/passwd -p war -k password-file

which will watch for **w**rite, **a**ppend, **r**ead operations on this file.

You can then retrieve the audit logs through the command:

> ausearch -f /etc/passwd

These examples are taken from [this article](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/linux-audit-files-to-see-who-made-changes-to-a-file.html) which provides a fuller overview of these commands. The **auditd** package typically includes these commands.

If you're only interested in monitoring operations on the files, and not who  actually performed those operations, you can use the [*inotifywatch*](http://linux.die.net/man/1/inotifywatch) command instead of enabling audit. This is typically available through the **inotify-tools** package. It records the filesystem events using linux's *inotify* interface.

Answer (score 3):

Auditd is your friend.

[Auditd man page](http://linux.die.net/man/8/auditd)

Not installed by default on most Linux distros yet though.

Answer (score 0):

The [`fuser`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/fuser) command does just that. Also, [`lsof`](http://www.netadmintools.com/html/lsof.man.html) does a similar job.

Note that `fuser` usually comes pre-installed on most distributions while `lsof` is less common, in my experience.

Comment: spatz, are you saying that fuser can be used to see that historically who all opened this file?

Comment: Not historically, right now. Maybe I misunderstood your question, but I thought you were looking for a way to see what process/user is accessing a particular file, and `fuser` does just that.

Answer (score 0):

Another way of doing this is inotify, http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/linux/library/l-inotify.html